# Changing Autopost Privacy Settings

Tags: facebook

I am not a professional developer, but I work with Facebook apps on a limited basis. I have a question on how to change the privacy settings on an app. What I mean by privacy settings is: I use Facebook apps to autopost between a blog and a business page. When I first linked the two, I accidentally set the settings -- through some kind of wizard that had popped up -- to show posts only to friends on the page owner. I want to show it to all; how would I go about changing that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the settings page and click on the App to change the privacy settings: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications